# Add a column to a multiple SELECT SQL query string

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The below code works, but I want to add the column "segvalue1" to my query result:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(DebitAmount-CreditAmount) as BalanceAmtCYTD 
FROM GLJrnDtl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE FiscalPeriod between 1 AND 10 
AND Company = 'NVV' AND FiscalYear = 2017),

(SELECT SUM(DebitAmount-CreditAmount) as BalanceAmtCYM 
FROM GLJrnDtl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE FiscalPeriod = 10 
AND Company = 'NVV' AND FiscalYear = 2017)
```

So I modified the code to look like the below but it gives me 2 "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS" errors :

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(DebitAmount-CreditAmount) as BalanceAmtCYTD, 
segvalue1 FROM GLJrnDtl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE FiscalPeriod 
between 1 AND 10 AND Company = 'NVV' AND FiscalYear = 2017 
GROUP BY segvalue1),

(SELECT SUM(DebitAmount-CreditAmount) as BalanceAmtCYM, 
segvalue1 FROM GLJrnDtl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE FiscalPeriod = 10 
AND Company = 'NVV' AND FiscalYear = 2017 
GROUP BY segvalue1)
```

Does anyone know how to modify the code to get my desired result? Again, I am just trying to pull in the segvalue1 column. Once I figure this out, I will also pull in a couple more columns. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code is basically unreadable.  I would suggest that you format the queries without the quotes and learn how to use parameters for passing in,well, parameter values.

Comment: What do you mean? It works , I just need to add a column.

Comment: By unreadable?  I took a quick look and chose not to bother.  Horizontal scrolling is too unpleasant.

Comment: I made it more readable! thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am just running queries on a read-only access MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT segvalue1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod BETWEEN 1 AND 10 
                THEN DebitAmount-CreditAmount 
                ELSE NULL 
           END) as BalanceAmtCYTD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod = 10 
                THEN DebitAmount-CreditAmount 
                ELSE NULL 
           END) as BalanceAmtCYM
FROM GLJrnDtl WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Company = 'NVV' AND FiscalYear = 2017             -- SHARED CONDITION
GROUP BY segvalue1
```

Comment: I get the below errors when running this code: 
System.Data.SQLClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.      Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: I don't see the word `with` in this answer.

Comment: Try removing `WITH (NOLOCK)` in `FROM` clause. Not sure what the issue with `CASE`.

Comment: ok I removed "WITH (NOLOCK)" and now I only get a "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE' "  error

Comment: Hmmm...again I cannot see why. This solution is syntactically correct. Check if you properly copied here or when extended for actual query: missing commas, parentheses as `CASE` should be wrapped in `SUM()`. Looks like you are using an application layer, C#. Print out SQL string to see if it is correct. Check too in Management Studio.

Comment: I just saw it, I was missing a coma after segvalue1

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and patience. Printing the string out did help me find that missing coma. I really like the conditional aggregation model. It seems really easy to read and understand. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: question though, does this mean I cannot do a "NOLOCK" ?

Comment: On second thought, I will research this and provide my findings  in a comment later in case someone else needs to know